# c++ wxWidgets Crash When Trying to Access wxTextCtrl Pointer outside of main

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm getting a very mysterious error that just makes no sense to me. I'm using CodeBlocks with a wxWidgets project. Inside the frame constructor, i create an object of the class fileManager. I then call a fileManager method that passes a TextCtrl from the GUI to fileManager for storage, so I'll be able to access the TextCtrl from within fileManager. The TextCtrl is called log_output. When I do this, i set a pointer in fileManager to the TextCtrl called local_log_output. Then when I try to call a different fileManager method and use that pointer in the method, the program crashes.

The mysterious part is the following. If this is my frame constructor:

```
MullSimple_3Frame::MullSimple_3Frame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(frame, -1, title, wxPoint(0, 0) )
{
    iniGUI();

    log_output->SetValue("HUH?");

    FileManager fileManager;
    fileManager.setLogOutput(log_output);

    std::map<int, std::string> prog_vars_deck_pairs = fileManager.getMenuPairs( "deck", "" );
}
```

the program works fine and does not crash. The fileManager.getMenuPairs method is called fine, which uses local_log_output. If however I move the call to fileManager.getMenuPairs to a seperate function in the frame, then call that function like so:

```
MullSimple_3Frame::MullSimple_3Frame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(frame, -1, title, wxPoint(0, 0) )
{
    iniGUI();

    log_output->SetValue("HUH?");

    FileManager fileManager;
    fileManager.setLogOutput(log_output);

    testMethod();
}


void MullSimple_3Frame::testMethod()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> prog_vars_deck_pairs = fileManager.getMenuPairs( "deck", "" );
}
```

The program crashes on the call to testMethod, and it stops on the line in getMenuPairs where I try to set the value of local_log_output.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the order that I'm declaring variables/functions in the frame constructor header matters? What other possible difference could there be where its not crashing in the first case but is crashing in the second case?

This is the header file for the frame

```
#ifndef MULLSIMPLE_2MAIN_H
#define MULLSIMPLE_2MAIN_H

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif


#include <vector>
#include "MullSimple_3App.h"
#include "non-wx/my_help_fxns.h"
#include "non-wx/file_manager.h"
#include "non-wx/data_vars.h"
#include "non-wx/simulator.h"


class MullSimple_3Frame: public wxFrame
{
    public:

        // constructor and destructor
        MullSimple_3Frame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title);
        ~MullSimple_3Frame();

        // logging output to terminal at bottom of gui
        wxTextCtrl *log_output;

        // reloads the deck load menu
        void menuDeckOptsReload();

        // just for trying to solve problem
        void testMethod();


        // VARIABLES

        int unique_wx_id = 1000;
        int curr_need_id = 0;
        int last_active_need_row_id = -1;

        std::vector<int> existing_needs_ids;
        std::vector<wxBoxSizer*> existing_needs_sizers;
        std::vector<need_layout_struct> existing_needs_items;
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> existing_needs_widget_ids;

        // WX GUI OBJECTS

        wxPanel *main_panel;
        wxMenu *deck_options_menu;
        wxMenu *load_deck_sub_menu;
        wxMenu *mull_options_menu;
        wxMenu *mull_load_all_sub_menu;
        wxMenu *mull_load_this_sub_menu;
        wxStaticText *deck_info_id;
        wxTextCtrl *deck_info_name;
        wxTextCtrl *deck_info_set;
        wxStaticText *deck_info_if_saved;
        wxStaticText *mull_info_id;
        wxTextCtrl *mull_info_name;
        wxStaticText *mull_info_if_saved;
        wxStaticText *deck_casts_title;
        wxStaticText *deck_lands_title;
        std::vector<wxTextCtrl*> deck_castable_inputs;
        std::vector<wxButton*> deck_castable_info_buts;
        std::vector<wxTextCtrl*> deck_land_inputs;
        std::vector<wxButton*> deck_land_info_buts;
        std::vector<wxTextCtrl*> hand_inputs;
        wxButton *mull_opts_but_add_need;
        wxButton *mull_opts_but_remove_need;
        wxButton *mull_opts_but_reset_needs;
        wxButton *mull_opts_but_simulate;
        wxBoxSizer *needs_sizer_wrap;


        // EVENT HANDLERS

        void eMenuDeckOptsNew(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuDeckOptsSave(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuDeckOptsLoad(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuMullOptsNew(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuMullOptsSave(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuMullOptsLoad(wxCommandEvent &event);
        void eMenuHandOptsClear(wxCommandEvent &event);


        // FUNCTIONS

        void iniMenu();
        void menuMullOptsReload();
        void iniGUI();
        void resetDeckInfo();
        void resetDeckInputs();
        void resetDeckInfoButs();
        void resetHandInputs();
        void resetMullInfo();
        void resetMullInputs();
        void deckCountCards();
        bool deckCheckSaved();
        void deckSortInputs(std::vector<std::string> deck_castable_strings, std::vector<std::string> deck_land_strings );
        void deckUpdateInfoButs();
        bool mullCheckSaved();
        void mullAddNeed(int insert_after_count);
        void mullNeedLineProcessRadiosAndChecks(need_layout_struct this_need_layout, std::string filter_class );



        // CLASS REFERENCES

        // file manager can save and load data
        FileManager fileManager;

        // data vars holds info about the cards in deck
        DataVars dataVars;

        // simulator sets up and runs sims
        Simulator simulator;


    private:

        // we don't use the event table for handling events, instead we use
        // connect for menu items and bind for controls, but still declare the table
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};


#endif // MULLSIMPLE_2MAIN_H
```

And here is the file manager header file:

```
#ifndef FILE_MANAGER_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE_MANAGER_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include "prog_structs.h"


    class FileManager
    {
        private:
    
    
        public:
    
            FileManager();
    
    
            // pointer to the gui log_output
            wxTextCtrl *local_log_output;
    
            // passed log_output from gui, sets a pointer to it for access within this class
            void setLogOutput(wxTextCtrl *log_output);

            // gets id/name pairs for saved decks to populate menu items
            std::map<int, std::string> getMenuPairs(
                std::string type, // "deck" or "mull"
                std::string deck_id  // only needed for mull, if we want only mull data related to a specific deck
            );
    
    };
    
    #endif // FILE_MANAGER_H_INCLUDED
```

And the file manager .cpp file

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <map>

#include "file_manager.h"
#include "my_help_fxns.h"

FileManager::FileManager()
{

}

void FileManager::setLogOutput(wxTextCtrl *log_output)
{
    local_log_output = log_output;
}
 
std::map<int, std::string> FileManager::getMenuPairs( std::string type, std::string deck_id )
{

    // PROGRAM IS CRASHING HERE, WHY I DON"T KNOW
    local_log_output->SetValue("PRINTING B...");

    std::map<int, std::string> menu_pairs;
    return menu_pairs;
}
```

EDIT: iniGUI()

```
    // mainPanel
    main_panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);

    // mainPanelSizer (vertical)
    wxBoxSizer *main_panel_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);


    // info sizer
        // deck info (id, name etc)
        // mull info (id, name etc)
    wxBoxSizer *info_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(info_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());


        // deckInfo (horizontal)
        // deck data along top like deck name, deck id, deck set
        wxBoxSizer *deck_info_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        info_sizer->Add(deck_info_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

            // DECK ID
            // label
            wxStaticText *label1 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "DECK ID: ");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(label1, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            deck_info_id = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "-1");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_id, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // DECK NAME
            // label
            wxStaticText *label2 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", NAME: ");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(label2, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            deck_info_name = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
            deck_info_name->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_3Frame::eDeckInfoChangeValue, this);
            deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_name, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // DECK SET
            // label
            wxStaticText *label3 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", SET: ");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(label3, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            deck_info_set = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
            deck_info_set->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_3Frame::eDeckInfoChangeValue, this);
            deck_info_set->Bind(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, &MullSimple_3Frame::eDeckInfoBlurSet, this);


            deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_set, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // DECK SAVED
            // can't do stuff unless the deck is saved. saving allows us to set data_vars.
            // label
            wxStaticText *label4 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", SAVED: ");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(label4, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            deck_info_if_saved = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "FALSE");
            deck_info_sizer->Add(deck_info_if_saved, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());


        wxBoxSizer *mull_info_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        info_sizer->Add(mull_info_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

            // MULL ID
            // label
            wxStaticText *label5 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "MULL ID: ");
            mull_info_sizer->Add(label5, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            mull_info_id = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "-1");
            mull_info_sizer->Add(mull_info_id, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());


            // MULL NAME
            // label
            wxStaticText *label6 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", NAME: ");
            mull_info_sizer->Add(label6, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            mull_info_name = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "");
            mull_info_name->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_3Frame::eMullInfoChangeValue, this);
            mull_info_sizer->Add(mull_info_name, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());


            // MULL SAVED
            // can't do stuff unless the deck is saved. saving allows us to set data_vars.
            // label
            wxStaticText *label7 = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, ", SAVED: ");
            mull_info_sizer->Add(label7, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

            // value
            mull_info_if_saved = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "FALSE");
            mull_info_sizer->Add(mull_info_if_saved, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());


    // progSizer (horizontal)
    // program contains 3 "columns"
    wxBoxSizer *prog_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer->Add(prog_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 1: DECK CASTABLES

    // castables column
    wxBoxSizer *deck_casts_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(deck_casts_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // castables title
    deck_casts_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Castables (0)", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxST_NO_AUTORESIZE);
    deck_casts_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
    deck_casts_sizer->Add(deck_casts_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // castables content
    // before we had just a single input arranged inside the sizer, but now i think
    // we want each row itself to be a sizer, with a button and an input

    for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {
        wxBoxSizer *card_item_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        deck_casts_sizer->Add(card_item_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // input
        this->unique_wx_id++;
        wxTextCtrl *card_input = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, this->unique_wx_id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));

        //card_input->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUIDeckCardsChangeValue, this);
        //card_input->Bind(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUICardsChangeAutoComplete, this);

        card_input->SetMinSize(wxSize(100, -1));
        deck_castable_inputs.push_back(card_input);
        card_item_sizer->Add(card_input, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // button
        this->unique_wx_id++;
        wxButton *card_info_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, this->unique_wx_id, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));
        card_info_but->SetName("deck_cast_info_but_" + myHelpFxns::ToWxString(std::to_string(i + 1)));
        //card_info_but->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUIDeckPrintCardInfo, this);
        deck_castable_info_buts.push_back(card_info_but);
        card_item_sizer->Add(card_info_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }



    // PROGRAM COLUMN 2: DECK LANDS

    wxBoxSizer *deck_lands_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(deck_lands_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // lands title
    deck_lands_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Lands (0)", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxST_NO_AUTORESIZE);
    deck_lands_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
    deck_lands_sizer->Add(deck_lands_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // lands content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
    {

        wxBoxSizer *card_item_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        deck_lands_sizer->Add(card_item_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // input
        this->unique_wx_id++;
        wxTextCtrl *card_input = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, this->unique_wx_id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));
        //card_input->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUIDeckCardsChangeValue, this);
        //card_input->Bind(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUICardsChangeAutoComplete, this);
        card_input->SetMinSize(wxSize(100, -1));
        deck_land_inputs.push_back(card_input);
        card_item_sizer->Add(card_input, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // button
        this->unique_wx_id++;
        wxButton *card_info_but = new wxButton(this->main_panel, this->unique_wx_id, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, -1));
        card_info_but->SetName("deck_land_info_but_" + myHelpFxns::ToWxString(std::to_string(i + 1)));
        //card_info_but->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUIDeckPrintCardInfo, this);
        deck_land_info_buts.push_back(card_info_but);
        card_item_sizer->Add(card_info_but, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 3: HAND

    wxBoxSizer *hand_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(hand_sizer, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // hand title
    wxStaticText *hand_title = new wxStaticText(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Hand", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 30), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    hand_title->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLUE);
    hand_sizer->Add(hand_title, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // hand content
    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        this->unique_wx_id++;
        wxTextCtrl *text_ctrl = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, this->unique_wx_id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 20));
        //text_ctrl->Bind(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, &MullSimple_3Frame::GUICardsChangeAutoComplete, this);
        text_ctrl->SetMinSize(wxSize(100, -1));

        hand_inputs.push_back(text_ctrl);
        hand_sizer->Add(text_ctrl, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());
    }


    // PROGRAM COLUMN 4: MULL OPTS

    // we'll set proportion 0 here and use the mull_opts_buttons to
    // set a fixed width for the sizer
    wxBoxSizer *mull_opts_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    prog_sizer->Add(mull_opts_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // MULL OPTS HORIZONTAL 1: MULL_OPTS_BUTTONS

    wxBoxSizer *mull_opts_but_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    mull_opts_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

        // add need button
        mull_opts_but_add_need = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "+ Need");
        mull_opts_but_add_need->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, 50));
        //mull_opts_but_add_need->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::globalNeedButAdd, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_add_need, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // remove need button
        mull_opts_but_remove_need = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "- Need");
        mull_opts_but_remove_need->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, 50));
        //mull_opts_but_remove_need->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::globalNeedButRemove, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_remove_need, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // reset all button
        mull_opts_but_reset_needs = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Reset All");
        mull_opts_but_reset_needs->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, 50));
        //mull_opts_but_reset_needs->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::globalNeedButReset, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_reset_needs, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        // calculate button
        mull_opts_but_simulate = new wxButton(main_panel, wxID_ANY, "Simulate");
        mull_opts_but_simulate->SetMinSize(wxSize(200, 50));
        //mull_opts_but_simulate->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MullSimple_3Frame::globalNeedButSimulate, this);
        mull_opts_but_sizer->Add(mull_opts_but_simulate, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());




    // needs sizer wrap, contains the needs, starts out empty
    needs_sizer_wrap = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    mull_opts_sizer->Add(needs_sizer_wrap, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    // MULL OPTS HORIZONTAL 2: NEEDS (in a stack)
    // Make on base need we can use as a model

    // at the bottom of the main panel stretches the log output
    // fixed height so set proportion 0
    wxBoxSizer *output_sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    main_panel_sizer ->Add(output_sizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Expand());

    log_output = new wxTextCtrl(main_panel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 200), wxTE_MULTILINE);
    log_output->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
    output_sizer ->Add(log_output, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

    // TAB ORDER CHANGES
    // tab order is annoying, no way to simply disable tabbing into an element.
    // so for things i don't want to tab into easily, i use this to put them after the log_ouput
    // which should be last in the panel
    mull_info_name->MoveAfterInTabOrder(log_output); // mull info name input for the mull set
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < deck_castable_info_buts.size(); i++ )
    {
        deck_castable_info_buts[i]->MoveAfterInTabOrder(log_output); // info buttons for each card (castables)
    }
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < deck_land_info_buts.size(); i++ )
    {
        deck_land_info_buts[i]->MoveAfterInTabOrder(log_output); // info buttons for each card (lands)
    }


    main_panel->SetSizerAndFit(main_panel_sizer);
    this->Fit();

}
```

Comment: do you run any threads? Does the program crashes or throws a debug alert? What pointer is `NULL` - that is meaning of the hard crash? Did you build the application and the library with exactly same toolchain? Did you use the proper options when you created a project?

Comment: Where do you initialize `local_log_output`?

Comment: local_log_output is initialized in the fileManager.setLogOutput method, which is called from the frame constructor

Comment: @Igor these are advanced questions for a newb programmer. Why would it not crash in the first case but crash in the second case? Emphasis on it did not crash in the first case, so how could possibly moving the call to fileManager.getMenuPairs to a different function inside the frame class then cause a crash?

Comment: @GeoffL, the answer is `I don't know`. Do you have more than one compiler installed? on the system?

Comment: No just a single compiler.....i was hoping the solution would be obvious because its such a weird problem, if its not a problem with my code and a problem with the compiler there's really nothing I can do about it i'm not going to spend days learning about compilers or the advanced inner workings of c++ to fix this, i'm just not that advanced yet

Comment: Right, I asked the wrong question. You initialize `local_log_output` to value of `log_output`, however, that field does not seem to be initialized by `MullSimple_3Frame` prior to call to `FileManager::setLogOutput`, hence my question stands: does the inital call to `log_output->SetValue("HUH?");` work? what's inside `iniGUI`? The problem you describe commonly indicate uninitialized pointer somewhere or access beyond array scope.

Comment: @orhtej2 Thanks for your reply. log_output is intialized in iniGUI() called before the log_output->("HUH"); test, so yes "HUH" works. I was careful to call iniGUI() before initializing fileManager so that the pointer exists, and if i use local_log_output within fileManaget.setLogOutput, that works too. i added iniGUI to the question so you can see

Comment: What I'm thinking is maybe, once the constructor is finished, and then i try to access fileManager from a different method inside the frame, the fileManager being used is actually maybe a different fileManager than the one in the constructor when i set the pointer? I don't think that's the problem but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @GeoffL, you are absolutely correct. You actually do have 2 objects of `FileManager`. One - a member of the class and another - inside a constructor. You never initialize the one that is a member, hence the crash. However the compiler should have warn you about variable hiding. And you throw this warning away.

Comment: @Igor Ahh i see now. Btw the compiler does not give a warning... I thought with classes, i had to declare them in the header file then initialize them in the constructor, but they're initialized when i declare them in the header.... that makes sense I guess. And cmon man I appreciate your help every time I post a Q but like I say every time I'm a C++ newb so you have to explain things like I'm a 5 year old

Comment: @GeoffL, this would be true if you declare a pointer as a class member. If you do that than constructor will nott be called, and you will have to do ` fileManager = new FileManagerr`. But then nobody would prevent you to declare the variable (not a pointer) inside the class - only the compiler warning. BTW you are probably compiling with the lowest possible warning level. But even then this warning should be generated. For the MinGW/gcc you should give `-Wall` option to the compiler.

Comment: Ah ok that's a good idea, my program is pretty big here come like 200 warnings but that's good I guess. I get a bit tripped up with using classes as i'm used to more procedural styles so I think I got it now. thanks